# Why does SudoSwap using opcode create not create2 to create a pair contract?

Tags: opcode, create

SudoSwap contract lib LSSVMPairCloner.sol

source code: https://github.com/sudoswap/lssvm/blob/main/src/lib/LSSVMPairCloner.sol

I don't understand why using opcode create not create2 to create a contract in LSSVMPairCloner.sol. What is the difference between create and create2? Is create better on gas saving?